# How to upload multiple files in codeigniter 3.0.1

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

How to upload multiple files in codeigniter 3.0.1. There are similar issues and solutions in stackoverflow but unfortunately non of them are helping to fix the issue I am facing.

This is the error message appearing `You did not select a file to upload` with my current code

**view (addGallery)**

```
<section>
    <h2>Add Gallery</h2>
        <?php echo form_open('Newsupload/gallery', ['id'=>'news', 'name'=>'news', 'method'=>'post','enctype'=>'multipart/form-data']) ?>

        <div class="grp width-50">
            <label for="name">Album Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" placeholder="">
        </div>
        <div class="grp width-100">
            <div id="selectedFiles"></div>
            <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple size="20"><br/>
        </div>
        <?php if (isset($error)) {
            echo $error;
        } ?>
        <grp class="grp width-100">
            <button>Add</button>
        </grp>
    </form>
</section>
```

**controller (gallery)**

```
public function gallery()
{

    $this->load->library('upload');

    $files = $_FILES;
    $cpt = count($_FILES['files']['name']);
    for($i=0; $i<$cpt; $i++)
    {           
        $_FILES['files']['name']= $files['files']['name'][$i];
        $_FILES['files']['type']= $files['files']['type'][$i];
        $_FILES['files']['tmp_name']= $files['files']['tmp_name'][$i];
        $_FILES['files']['error']= $files['files']['error'][$i];
        $_FILES['files']['size']= $files['files']['size'][$i];    

        $this->upload->initialize($this->set_upload_options());
        // $this->upload->do_upload('files[]');
        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('files[]'))
        {  
            $error =['error' => $this->upload->display_errors()];
            $this->load->view('admin/addGallery', $error);
        }
    }
}
public function set_upload_options()
{
    $config['upload_path'] = getcwd().'/upload/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png';
    $config['remove_spaces'] = true;
    return $config;
}
```

Comment: $this->upload->do_upload('files');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default codeIgniter doesn't support multi-file upload. So you can use 
this library [CodeIgniter Multiple Upload Library](https://github.com/anuragrath/CodeIgniter-Multiple-File-Upload)

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to change this line:

```
if (!$this->upload->do_upload('files[]'))
```

to

```
if (!$this->upload->do_upload('files'))
```

Answer (score 2):

you did not pass file name to upload function.Try this.

```
if (!$this->upload->do_upload($_FILES['files']['name']))
        {  
            $error =['error' => $this->upload->display_errors()];
            $this->load->view('admin/addGallery', $error);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
      $files = $_FILES;
        $cpt = count($_FILES['files']['name']);
         for($i=0; $i<$cpt; $i++)
        {
        $_FILES['files']['name']= $files['files']['name'][$i];
        $_FILES['files']['type']= $files['files']['type'][$i];
        $_FILES['files']['tmp_name']= $files['files']['tmp_name'][$i];
         $_FILES['files']['error']= $files['files']['error'][$i];
         $_FILES['files']['size']= $files['files']['size'][$i];
        $this->upload->initialize($this->set_upload_options());
        $this->upload->do_upload();
        $fileName = $_FILES['files']['name'];
         $images[] = $fileName;
```

and make a function set_upload_options()

```
$config = array();
         $config['upload_path'] = './upload/'; //give the path to upload the image in folder
         $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
          $config['max_size'] = '0';
         $config['overwrite'] = FALSE;
  return $config;
```

For more Upload multiple files using codeigniter try this http://w3code.in/2015/09/upload-file-using-codeigniter/

Comment: i tried this code ,but i got given error  Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: _file

Filename: libraries/Upload.php

Line Number: 408

Comment: Had you make the function set_upload_options() ?

Answer (score 0):

Please try bellow

```
for($i=0; $i<$cpt; $i++)
{           
    $_FILES['files'] =  $files[$i];
    $this->upload->initialize($this->set_upload_options());
    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('files'))
    {  
        $error =['error' => $this->upload->display_errors()];
        $this->load->view('admin/addGallery', $error);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can upload multiple files with CodeIgniter in a single request. You just need to do `do_upload()` for each file. Here's one implementation. You can work it into a loop if needed.

```
    // Image upload Config
    $config['upload_path']   = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png';
    $config['max_size']      = '1000000';
    $config['encrypt_name']  = TRUE;
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    // Upload Files
    if ( $_FILES['first_file']['name'] && $this->upload->do_upload('first_file') ) {
        $first_file = $this->upload->data();
    }
    if ( $_FILES['second_file']['name'] && $this->upload->do_upload('second_file') ) {
        $second_file= $this->upload->data();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just that i understood from the library `$this->upload->do_upload('inputelementname')` doesn't have to be input element name. It should be the key of files array.

So in this context this should work

```
if($_FILES){
              $filecount=count($_FILES['addmediaelement']['name']);
              for($i=0; $i<$filecount; $i++){
                  $_FILES['mediaelement']['name']=$_FILES['addmediaelement']['name'][$i];
                  $_FILES['mediaelement']['type']=$_FILES['addmediaelement']['type'][$i];
                  $_FILES['mediaelement']['tmp_name']=$_FILES['addmediaelement']['tmp_name'][$i];
                  $_FILES['mediaelement']['error']=$_FILES['addmediaelement']['error'][$i];
                  $_FILES['mediaelement']['size']=$_FILES['addmediaelement']['size'][$i];

                  $config['upload_path']=path/to/save/file;
                  $config['file_name']=filealternatename.extension;
                  $config['max_size']=MAXSIZE; //max size constant
                  $config['max_width']=MAXWIDTH; //max width constant
                  $config['max_height']=CMPMAXHEIGHT; //max height constant
                  $config['allowed_types']='jpg|png';

                  if(!is_dir($config['upload_path'])){
                      mkdir($config['upload_path'], 0775);
                  }
                  $this->upload->initialize($config);
                  $imageuploaderres[]=$this->upload->do_upload('mediaelement');
              }
          }
```