# uploading a array of files using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a form which uploads a **title** and a **file**. The user can dynamically add the fields

```
<input type="text" name="title[]" />
<input type="file" name="userfile[]" />
```

That's why have used an array.

The problem is that i cant find a way to upload the files through the codeigniters upload.

Below is my code

```
foreach ($_FILES as $i => $file) {
    $config['upload_path'] = './files';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg';
    $config['max_size'] = 1024;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->do_upload($file);

    $file = $this->upload->data();
    echo $path = $file['file_name'];
}
```

But `$path` is always empty and no files are being uploaded.

When I `var_dump($_FILES);` it shows all the files

Can some one tell me how I can upload the files when it's an array?

Comment: Can you post the `var_dump` output as well ?

Comment: do you have `enctype='multipart/form-data'` on your form tag?

Comment: @WEBjuju yep.. I have that in my tag

Comment: please show us the `var_dump` of `$_FILES`

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, Codeigniter doesn't handle multiple file uploads out of the box, even in version 3.x.

There is a third part [CodeIgniter Multiple Upload Library](https://github.com/anuragrath/CodeIgniter-Multiple-File-Upload) that is commonly prescribed, but it hasn't been updated in about 4 years. I don't know what it's status is at the moment.

There's another SO question that has some other things to try as well:

[How to upload multiple files in codeigniter 3.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32964931/how-to-upload-multiple-files-in-codeigniter-3-0-1)

There is a method around that does the trick to, using `$this->upload->initialize($config);` in your loops through the uploaded files. There's a gist here:

https://gist.github.com/zitoloco/1558423