# multiple file upload and single file upload on same page using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

I have tried to upload multiple files and profile pic on a single page but it does not work properly.

```
/** multiple file upload**/
if (!empty($_FILES['attach_file']['name'])) {
    $upload = do_upload($_FILES, $folder);
    if (count($upload) > 0) {
        foreach ($upload as $key => $status) {
            if ($status == 1) {
                $form_data = array(
                    'user_id' => $user_id,
                    'image_name' => $key
                );
                $this->Providerfiles_model->insert($form_data);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am using this code for multi file uploading but it doesn't work. It's uploading only one document.

```
/***profile pic uplod**/
if ($_FILES && $_FILES['file1']['name'] != "") {
    $folder = FCPATH . 'upload/';
    if ($this->upload->do_upload('file1')) {
        $image_data = $this->upload->data();
        $pic_data = array(
            'user_id' => $user_id,
            'title' => $image_data['file_name']
        );
        $this->profilepic_model->insert($pic_data);
        $image_id = $this->db->insert_id();
    }
}
```

I am using this code for profile pic upload. It's working fine but when I upload multiple documents and profile pic together it's not working properly. Documents  will be saving in profile pic table and I am not able to find the solution for this.

This is the function I am using for multiple file uploading in helper

```
/** do_upload() in helper**/
function do_upload($files, $folder_name) {
    $return = array();
    $ci = & get_instance();
    $cpt = count($files['attach_file']['name']);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $cpt; $i++) {
        $image = $files['attach_file']['name'][$i];
        $config['file_name'] = $image;
        $_FILES['userfile']['name'] = $image;
        $_FILES['userfile']['type'] = $files['attach_file']['type'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] = $files['attach_file']['tmp_name'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['error'] = $files['attach_file']['error'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['size'] = $files['attach_file']['size'][$i];
        $ci->upload->initialize($config);

        if ($ci->upload->do_upload()) {
            $data = $ci->upload->data();
            $return[$data['file_name']] = 1;
        } else {
            $return[$image] = 0;
        }
    }

    return $return;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32967720/1423831

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upload multiple files in codeigniter 3.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32964931/how-to-upload-multiple-files-in-codeigniter-3-0-1)

Comment: facing problem when upload profile pic and multiple files on same page and save their data on different tables.